# How to programmatically enable a Service?

Tags: cocoa, system-preferences

I have an application that provides a service to modify text that is currently selected. However, it has to be first enabled by the user through the Keyboard Shortcuts section of System Preferences.

Is there a way for me to enable it for the user?